# how to add particular character in starting of each line in text file using vi

Tags: text-processing, vi

Let's suppose we have a text file which contains the below entries.

```
my name is XYZ

I study at ABC school
```

if using vi mode I want to add "#" in front of each line
`:%s/^/#/g`The issue is that "#" will also insert in the text file's blank line, but I only want to add "#" in front of non-blank lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
:%s/^./#&/
```

where

- `:` command mode
- `%` all lines
- `s/LHS/RHS/` substitue Left Hand Side by Right Hand Side
- `^` begin if line
- `.` one char
- `#`
- `&` what we find

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that you want to avoid adding `#` at the start of "blank" lines, i.e. lines that may be empty or contain only spaces or tabs.

Inserting `#` at the start of each line that contains a non-blank character:

```
:g/[^[:blank:]]/ s/^/#/
```

This uses the `g` ("global") command inherited from the `ed` editor to apply a substitution on each line that matches the regular expression `[^[:blank:]]`.  This expression matches a line that contains at least one non-blank character.  A "blank character" (in the POSIX locale) is a tab or a space.

A command with the same effect:

```
:v/^[[:blank:]]*$/ s/^/#/
```

This uses `v` in place of `g` to apply the same substitution on each line that does *not* match the expression `^[[:blank:]]*$`, i.e. that is empty or only contains blanks.  The `v` command is also inherited from the `ed` editor.

Would you additionally want to avoid adding `#` to lines that already start with `#`, then change the substitution in the above commands to `s/^#\?/#/`.  This would insert a `#` on non-blank lines, but *replace* a `#` at the start if there was one.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do:

`:%norm I#`

Which for every line `%` applies the `norm`al mode command `I` to insert at the start of the line (ignoring leading whitespace) and enters the character `#`.

The nice thing about this approach is that you can apply any sequence of normal mode commands - they're a bit like macros in that sense (and by using `:g/pattern/norm I#` you could apply them to lines matching `pattern`).